# Twilio call forwarding just hangs up

Tags: twilio

I'm just following the instructions. From my Twilio dashboard, it shows the call incoming but no calls outgoing. What am I missing? Do I have to set a call forwarding option somewhere? I don't see any.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+6612345678</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Can you check to make sure enabled international privilages for the country you are tryin to dial?  https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international

Comment: thanks, but I don't see Thailand on the list. Does that mean call forwarding is not available from my US number to a local Thailand number?

Comment: Not sure why you are not seeing it.  Its listed under Asia.  Did you try using the filter box o nthe top right if the page?

Comment: Bahrain  (+973)    more
 China  (+86)    more
 Hong Kong  (+852)    more
 India  (+91)    more
 Israel  (+972)    more
 Japan  (+81)    more

Comment: I only see the countries listed above. What do you think?

Comment: not sure.  At this point I'

Comment: Ah, right.  For Thailand you're going to need to request access:  https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international/dialing-permissions

Comment: Okay, I just submitted a form. Wish these things were more obvious, as the instructions for setting up call forwarding made no mention of it. Thank you